# Is it possible to overload the C# dynamic type property resolution?

Tags: c#, dynamic

Is it possible to overload how a type resolves properties when cast to dynamic?

Basically what I am trying to do is something like `ExpandoObject` where you can access new properties on the fly, but instead of those properties being whatever gets assigned to them, I want them all to be collections of strings, and when you access one, it calls a dictionary web service which returns all of the definitions of the word.  I want it to be dynamic so that you can specify any word at all.

I'm thinking the usage would be something like this:

```
dynamic dictionary = new DictionaryWebservice();
var awesome = dictionary.awesome;

foreach(var definition in awesome)
{
    // add definition to my output
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, derive your type from [System.Dynamic.DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx).

Remember though that everything you return from a dynamic method is itself `dynamic`. Therefore, even the `var definition` in your `foreach` will be of type `dynamic`.

Comment: [Just link here next time you need a short comment ☺](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/)